# Escaping strings passed to a sqlsrv_connect function

Tags: php

I have been using the sqlsrv driver for PHP and have an array of connection details which I then pass to the `sqlsrv_connect()`.

This has worked fine for standard passwords, however, it has run into trouble when I tried a password string which contained a `$` symbol and got the following notice:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: xxxx in \\xxxx\classes\Class.Database.php
```

The undefined variable is all the characters after the `$` symbol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write the password between single quotes, like this:

```
'the$pwd'
```

Instead of double quotes:

```
"the$pwd"
```

In double quotes, variables are interpolated; this is equivalent to `"the".$pwd`

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing for more informations.